# Russian Soyuz MS-09 Launch - back and forth rotation of the second stage (along the length axis). Precession?

Tags: rockets, astrodynamics

In the ISS Expedition 56-57 Launch of Russian Soyuz MS-09, in the first view from the external camera at around 3:30, an obvious back and forth rotation (along the length axis) of the rocket can be seen against the earth background.
Its amplitude diminishes until it is no longer visible around 4:30.

Is the rocket precessing? Why?
And why does this precession decrease? Active correction?

[Here](https://youtu.be/ojjE701htNg?t=3m17s) is a video where you can see it from 3:15. I estimate fhe frequency of the phenomenon to be 0.5-0.7 Hz.

Comment: I think it's called "roll"?

Comment: @uhoh I would interpret *roll* more as a one-time phenomenon. Here the camera looks down along the rocket and you see it rotate back and forth (that's why I can't conclude from the video that it *is* precession). But I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: @JanDoggen "roll" is generally any rotation around the longitudinal axis of a vehicle (usually considered the X axis).  The video shows what would be generally considered a roll oscillation. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c1/Yaw_Axis_Corrected.svg/250px-Yaw_Axis_Corrected.svg.png It looks like an attitude correction with poor damping in the control system.